# Efficiently sorting and grouping really big arrays

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, sorting, numpy

I am sorting an array of data based on the angle each point within the data forms with the other points. For my given `data` (x,y,z), i calculate the pairwise distance (`pwdist`), the pairwise value (`pwresi`) and the angle between pair data point (`pwang`). Once i get this, i groups the data into various classes (defined by the angles ranging from 0 to 180 with steps of 30) by looking at the index of the data and its corresponding angle. Then for each class, I estimate the variance/semivariance. For clarity, I have added my code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
data = pd.read_excel(filepath)
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
nrow, dummy_cols = data.shape

pwdist = squareform(pdist(data[:,:2]))
pwresi = (data[:,2, None] - data[:,2])**2
pwang = np.arctan2((data[:,1, None] - data[:,1]), (data[:,0, None] - data[:,0]))*180/np.pi

vecdistance = pwdist.ravel()
vecresidual = pwresi.ravel()
vecangle = pwang.ravel()

sortdistance = defaultdict(list)
sortresidual = defaultdict(list)
sortangle = defaultdict(list)
lagangle = []
count = -1
get_anglesector = 30

for j in range(0, 180, get_anglesector):
    count += 1
    for k, dummy_val in enumerate(vecangle):
        if j <= vecangle[k] < j + get_anglesector:
            sortdistance[count].append(vecdistance[k])
            sortresidual[count].append(vecresidual[k])
            sortangle[count].append(vecangle[k])
    lagangle.append((j+get_anglesector/2))

uniquedistance = {}
classdistance = {}
summation = {}
semivariance = {}

for i, dummy_val in enumerate(sortdistance):
    uniquedistance[i] = np.unique(sortdistance[i])
    classdistance[i] = np.searchsorted(uniquedistance[i], sortdistance[i])
    summation[i] = np.bincount(classdistance[i], weights=sortresidual[i])
    semivariance[i] = summation[i]/(2*np.bincount(classdistance[i]))
```

The code works quite well until when I have to group the data into classes (that is; in code, from `for j in range(0, 180, get_anglesector):`) . For data with less than 500 points, this code is okay. But I am running data of over 10,000 point and so time is crucial. Is there an efficient/pythonic way to write this code to increase performance?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your code messy, and your question is not fully understandable.

So my answer is theoretical, and you should apply it to your own case:

Given, a list:
`myList = [element1, element2, element3]`

And known, an evaluation function: `def eval(a): return angle(a.x, a.y)` for example

You can just use the fast sort python has (I think they use quick-sort) which is O(n*log(n)) to sort it, by doing:

`sortedList = mylist.sort(key=lambda a: angle(a.x, a.y))`

This method assigns a numeric value for each of the elements in the list, which is sortable.